Add column by accessing item in Array based on ID without SQL expression
I have the following data in a dataframe df:
{
    "data":[
        {
            "id":"a",
            "val":1
        },
        {
            "id":"b",
            "val":2
        }
    ]
}

I would now like to add a new column "test" for the id 'b' containing its value 2.
I know I can do this with:
(
    df
    .withColumn(
        "test",
        F.expr("filter(data,x->x.id=='b')")[0]["val"]
    )
    .show()
)


Yielding the desired:
+----------------+----+
| data           |test|
+----------------+----+
|[{a, 1}, {b, 2}]| 2  |
+----------------+----+

Could this be achieved in a more "native" way (not using SQL)? I know that F.col("data")[1]["val"] can be used if I go by index rather than ID as an example.

I'm not sure that by you mentioning "not using SQL", you also exclude sqlalchemy or not. but from personal experience sqlalchemy is a really good way to handle this kind of situation. It is a python extension. pip install SQLAlchemy

@ParSaMnS I am rather new to PySpark. "not using SQL" means not falling back to F.expr(). Its very possible this is a good way to handle it - in this case my question would be obsolete, but it seemed to me there should be a more "native" solution; hence the question.

I have uploaded an answer with some links that might help! Please keep me updated on whether it works or not because I am also invested in this :)

When you said you want to achieve in more "native" way (not using SQL), do you want to filter it based on Spark API or use Python code to do the filtering?

@Jonathan I was thinking about Spark API, but any alternative would by interesting to me

Do you mean like this F.filter('data', lambda x: x.id == 'b')[0].val?

@Emma this actaully does not work for me. apparently F.filter() does not support lambda expressions

Which version of spark are you using? F.filter is v3.1+. If you are using 3.1+, could you update your question with your updated code?  filter should take lambda

@Emma which code should be updated exactly? Spark version in 15.3.x-scala2.12

Are you using Databricks 15.3? that should be Spark 3.5, filter should work on 3.5. Could you show your updated code with lambda and show any errors you are seeing?

@Emma it works properly, just as you suggested -I am sorry for any inconvenience, I must have had a typo... could you post your suggestion as an answer, so I can accept it please?

You can try filter in Pyspark API.
df.withColumn("test", 
              F.filter('data', lambda x: x.id == 'b')[0].val)


If im not mistaken, you can use DataFrame transformations. By flattening the nested structure within the data column. Then you filter out the id row where it equals to b and select val column from the filtered out rows. Then you join this DataFrame to the original DataFrame to add it to the new column.
Here are some links that can help to further understand this concept:
Stack overflow
geeksforgeeks
Medium
